# The use of bullet points in formal writing

Tags: grammar, formal-language

I have encountered a problem when I was proofreading one of my essays. The example is as follows:

"To help you make a decision, I have found five possible locations for you to consider.The specific information on these locations can be found xxx website.

- List item
- List item
- List item
- List item
- List item"

I think I have to use a colon before the first bullet point, but it seems like that I can't in this example. Can someone provide some help on how to fix this example. Thanks very much!

Comment: In *very* formal writing, bullet points would not be used.  Constitutions, certain legal documents, treaties, etc.

Comment: You could move "The specific information on these locations..." under the list, and use a colon after *consider*.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a colon before every list. You can leave your example as it is. It might be possible to make the sentences flow together better by rephrasing.

> Location is important when making your decision. You can find information about possible locations at the website at xxx. There are five locations that I have found for you to consider:

Answer (score 1):

I am confused by the question itself. What do you mean that "it seems that" you can't use a colon? The relevant question ought to be whether you should use a colon. The problem with questions about punctuation is that there is no universal agreement. In formal writing, the best solution is to pick a style guide and adhere to it. Others may prefer a different guide, but at least you will have some basis for your choice. Personally, I like to introduce a list with a colon to make clear that the list is effectively part of the sentence.

Like James K, I find your proposed sentence awkward. I might try

> Detailed information on five locations that may be particularly relevant to your decision can be found:
>
> ```
>  Here;
>
>  Here;
>
>  Here;
>
>  Here, and
>
>  Here.
> ```